# Capture screenshot of an element without resizing the viewport of cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-psoc

I have set up viewport as below.

```
Cy.viewport(1440,700)
```

Then taking the screenshot

```
Cy.get('xxxx').toMatchImageSnapshot()
```

But when taking screenshot, the browser is resizing to fit to the browser window size.  How to control the browser resizing.

Cypres package v- 8.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either override the default `fullPage` capture option when taking the screenshot like this:

```
cy.get('xxxx').toMatchImageSnapshot({capture: 'viewport'});
```

Or set it globally in `cypress/support/index.js` file like this:

```
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
  capture: 'viewport'
});
```

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/screenshot#Arguments